# perl cgi jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, perl, cgi

So I did a 2 test pages, one in perl cgi and another in html, to test out the jquery scripts but surprisingly, only the html one works. I need to do it in the perl cgi so I don't know what is the problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI;
my $query = new CGI;
print "Content-type: text/html\n";
print qq(
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="tablesorter/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="tablesorter/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function()
            {
                jQuery("#myTable").tablesorter();
            }
            );
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Due</th>
                    <th>Web Site</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Smith</td>
                    <td>John</td>
                    <td>jsmith@gmail.com</td>
                    <td>\$50.00</td>
                    <td>http://www.jsmith.com</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Bach</td>
                    <td>Frank</td>
                    <td>fbach@yahoo.com</td>
                    <td>\$50.00</td>
                    <td>http://www.frank.com</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Doe</td>
                    <td>Jason</td>
                    <td>jdoe@hotmail.com</td>
                    <td>\$100.00</td>
                    <td>http://www.jdoe.com</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Conway</td>
                    <td>Tim</td>
                    <td>tconway@earthlink.net</td>
                    <td>\$50.00</td>
                    <td>http://www.timconway.com</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
);
```

Comment: Define "works". What happens when you try the CGI version? You're showing us some Perl, but aren't even saying if your problem is related to generating the output from the Perl that you want of if the JavaScript you are generating with it isn't doing what you expect.

Comment: The output is there but the jquery function doesnt work

Comment: What output? If it doesn't work, what does it do? What errors are reported on the error console? What does the developer tool Net tab say? What do the server error logs say?

Answer (score 1):

The output of a CGI script is exactly the same as a static HTML page from the browser's point of view.  Therefore, if your Perl script is working and outputting the exact same content as your HTML page, it will work exactly the same.

What happens when you *view source* in your browser after running the CGI script?  Look there for differences between the non-working and the working version.

(In case you are very new at this: if you see the Perl code in the browser, that means your server is not set up properly and you are not executing CGI at all.  Perl runs on the server side.)

Comment: its exactly the same but just that the cgi script doesn't have the jquery functionality

Comment: @user2285115, is the CGI script located in the same directory as the other file?  You are using relative paths to your Javascript files; maybe the paths are not correct relative to the directory in which you are running the script.

Answer (score 1):

Escape $ it with a backslash, as $( is considered a variable in Perl